# Mysterious beige seeds with a trough cleaved through them

Tags: seeds

I found these seeds packed away. I have no idea what they are, nor how old they are.

They are beige color, about 5 millimeters wide. A distinct trough runs through them from end-to-end, about 2 millimeters wide and 2 millimeters deep, colored darker yellow-brown. The trough is quite deep and wide, like a tiny [router tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_%28woodworking%29) was run through it.

➠ What might they be?

[image]

Nut puffed cereal, really! Firm little things I found tucked away in that yellow packet, so I *assume* they are seeds.

Comment: My first thought was OAT seed.  Looks like puffed oat seeds.  Be back later, what is that cereal, puffed oats?

Comment: https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.RjtmIVSiwYPQq1kP1TZSNQDgEs&pid=Api  No this is in no way the answer to the type of seed but weird...never have seen a seed like this.

Comment: Take one of them and use your thumbnail to try to cut one...what does it look like inside?  I'd try to get one started in a paper towel that is a bit over damp.  Not too soggy, but warm, no light...put a few of these seeds in a paper towel and then inside a zip lock.  With air.  Wait 2 days...you should see the seed germinate.  Maybe 3 days?  What fun...

Comment: I don't know why I am a bit hung up on Mung Beans, check out this image; rather GREEN GRAM; https://www.bing.com/cr?IG=3DF3AD1D26EA48F39A5E2337FD04FBC0&CID=29E41AD7341961972EC410023546603D&rd=1&h=TUpUXRP5myQ4mwqHhwPb3kM51Swu7zPy2uu_rw4ZsHo&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.directgardening.com%2f242-thickbox_default%2fmung-beans-sprouting-seeds.jpg&p=DevEx,5164.1

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/A_view_of_greengram_fry.jpg/800px-A_view_of_greengram_fry.jpg     Check this image as well...how old do you think these seeds are?

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost certain what you have are lotus seeds. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_seed

They're usually a pale ivory colour and as they age, deepen to a more light golden-tan. Since colours can be deceptive viewed over the internet, I can't say how fresh the ones you have are.

Packaged like yours, perhaps they were meant to be planted *unless* they've been repackaged by someone. There appears to be much more than is needed to start new plants so I'd hazard a guess these were meant for food. In fact,  I have an unopened package of lotus seeds in my pantry as I cook a lot of Asian foods.

Lotus seeds are commonly used in Asian cooking. They're used to make lotus seed paste (quite yummy) as a filling in festive moon cakes. They're also added to soups. Lotus seeds are considered a 'yin' food noted for their cooling effect and clearing 'excess heat' in traditional Chinese medicine.

Some photos of lotus seeds. The first one is from Wikipedia. Please let me know if your seeds match the photos.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me, though obviously, the ones in the question's picture are well past their best

Comment: I agree they look old. My package is sealed and air tight as it should be. To be honest, I'm not sure if lotus seeds for planting have to be **very** fresh or they won't germinate - much like passiflora seeds.

Comment: Indeed, my sample in the Question may be decade old or more.

Comment: Saying just how old they are, Basil, makes me all the more convinced they're lotus seeds. Whether they were meant to plant or to eat is moot now. They wouldn't be fit for either. As they continued to dry out, the split would open wider (as it's pretty snugly closed in fresh lotus seeds) exposing the inside to further darkening through oxidation. If I hadnt seen lotus seeds (by using them in Asian cooking), I'd have no idea. But using them makes me more certain.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've been out in identify seed land and I stumbled across genetically modified soybean seeds.  What caught my eye was this TROUGH looking like it was router made.  Check this out.  I am not sure it is lotus seed as I couldn't see the thingy (Hilum) that shows up on his seed.  I don't think this is an answer but I gotta throw this out there. The other thing was the envelope they came in!  Check this stuff out...[GMO soybean seed in the process of modification](http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=A943676A26E14BFDA785C2D082F53535&CID=17E2B006D4606F072377BAD3D53F6E65&rd=1&h=dQnBWD3-fcp16fB0WAwSlCLffy0WmzqFjVr_DNg85EU&v=1&r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.popsci.com%2Fsites%2Fpopsci.com%2Ffiles%2Fstyles%2Fmedium_1x_%2Fpublic%2Fimport%2F2013%2Fimages%2F2011%2F01%2Fsoybeans.jpeg%3Fitok%3D7DBpO3gW&p=DevEx,5152.1)

Do you know anything about the original owners of these seeds?  Were they Monsanto employees????  Grins!  This second picture is of all types of soybean in an envelope just like the one your seeds are in...weird. [a multitude of soybean colors and types](http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=11A7EECC0C96470587D4A62249F8F613&CID=2D56A27CB6D5619E166EA8A9B78A6040&rd=1&h=7G7XITdyqgq2XuHrNFtzo9FzVdOZHLQGph4ERrE91SE&v=1&r=http%3A%2F%2Fimagecache.jpl.nasa.gov%2Fimages%2F640x350%2Fsoybean20140415b-640-640x350.jpg&p=DevEx,5242.1)

I like the lotus seed idea as that would be something I most certainly would love to take from Egypt or where ever to bring home and try to grow.  Pretty tough to do these days.  I am not at all sure on this ID!  Interesting about the router trough, package with no identification???